# Load images from upload folder into module HMVC codeginiter

Tags: codeigniter

I have the next tree in my HMVC application.

```
-application
   -modules
      -moduleOne
         -assets
         -controllers
         -models
         -views
         -uploads
            -images
```

What i need is to load images (From the uploads/images folder) in a view. How can i do that? The assets folder is working fine, but i need to have the uploads folder separated.

I'm using Assets library:
In application/modules/moduleOne/controllers/Assets.php i have:

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

// include the global Assets class
include(APPPATH.'libraries/Assets.php');
```

And in libraries/Assets.php

```
 <?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');


class Assets extends MX_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

    }

    function index(){
        //$this->user->authorize();

         if(count($this->uri->segments)==2){
             show_error("Serving assets for: ".APPPATH. 'modules/' . implode('/', $this->uri->segments));
             exit;
         }
        //---get working directory and map it to your module
        $file = APPPATH. 'modules/' . implode('/', $this->uri->segments);
        //----get path parts form extension
        $path_parts = pathinfo( $file);
        //---set the type for the headers
        $file_type=  strtolower($path_parts['extension']);

        if (is_file($file)) {
            //----write propper headers
            switch ($file_type) {
                case 'css':
                    header('Content-type: text/css');
                    break;

                case 'js':
                    header('Content-type: text/javascript');
                    break;

                case 'json':
                    header('Content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8');
                    break;

                case 'xml':
                   header('Content-type: text/xml');
                    break;

                case 'pdf':
                  header('Content-type: application/pdf');
                    break;
                case 'svg':

                    header('Content-type: image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8');
                    break;

                case 'jpg' || 'jpeg' || 'png' || 'gif':
                    header('Content-type: image/'.$file_type);
                    break;
            }

            readfile($file);
        } else {
            show_error("Asset not found: $file");
        }
        exit;
    }

}
```

It allows me to use assets inside my module. But I need to make the reference in the img src to the uploads/images folder.

Comment: what code u use for assets folder

Comment: @pradeep i edited the question. This is the code

Comment: why can't you access `localhost/application/modules/somemodule/images/someimage.jpg` directly?

Comment: Because Codeigniter doesn't let you to do that haha